# Charging a Li-po battery (battery output current)

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, power, battery, solar-energy

I would like to design a buck converter to use a PV panel to charge a [11.1V 3000mAh 3S 30C Lipo battery](https://www.amazon.co.uk/FLOUREON-3000mAh-Rechargeable-Airplane-Helicopter/dp/B01ITCMZ44).

I want to choose the minimum inductance for a CCM ($L=\dfrac{V_{out}T_s}{2I_{out}}$), what is the output current that I need to charge this battery? should $V_{out}=11.1\text{ V}$ and $I_{out}=3000\text{ mAh}$?

Comment: 3000mAh is not a current.

Comment: LiPo batteries require a strict CV/CC curve to charge correctly and safely. I suggest that you take the time to research the charge characteristics of lithium polymer batteries before playing with them.

Comment: Agree with @DonaldGibson. You can just buy an off the shelf LiPo charger and hook your PV panel up to it.  Most LiPo chargers accept DC input over a fairly generous voltage range that should be suitable for your PV panel.